# Transact Sql LEFT function weird output

Tags: sql, t-sql, select

```
select replace(stuff('123456',2,2,'ABCD'),'1',' ')

select LEFT('ABCD456',4)

select left(replace(stuff('123456',2,2,'ABCD'),'1',' '),4)
```

Ok now the first select outputs 'ABCD456', the series of functions evaluates to that
exactly the first parameter to the left function in the second select
second select returns 'ABCD' as expected
third select returns 'ABC'

Why? Shouldn't it also output 'ABCD'?
Does anybody know?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is clearer if you do

```
select '[' + left(replace(stuff('123456',2,2,'ABCD'),'1',' '),4) + ']'
```

which returns

```
[ ABC]
```

There is a leading space!

`select stuff('123456',2,2,'ABCD')` Gives `1ABCD456`

Then you replace the 1 with a space